# Cross domain content loading with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

Ok, here's the problem:

The remote site needs to pull complex html page content from other domain. Iframe solution is not good enough because of the problem with determining the page height, and cross domain ajax is not allowed on IE browsers. There is JSONP but amount of code that needs to be served is too complex and we also need to serve some funcionalities.

The solution:

On server side we are dinamically generating javascript that contains all the complex html content in a  string variable. On remote side we just include call to this script and we put a  on the page. Div is then filled with content from served variable. It works cross domain on ALL browsers and the content displays perfectly :)).

The question:

What's wrong with this approach? Why there is no mention of such solution anywhere online? It seems perfect for serving any kind of widgets and alike content, and now I'm affraid there is some big fallacy in it:)?

Please debunk it :)

Comment: It's essentially just a home-made version of JSONP.

Comment: Well yes. But this way the whole html page from remote server can be served together with all javascript funcionalities on it. We weren't able to achieve this with jsonp.

Comment: "*... and cross domain Ajax is not allowed on IE browsers.*" - Well, at least the other browsers let you do that.. Oh, wait, they don't.

Comment: Well, it might have complicated things to use JSONP, but what I mean is that it exploits the same browser capability that underlies JSONP.

Comment: Well they do with json and jsonp, but you can even serve html with setting  Access-Control-Allow-Origin = * in response headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with this approach. Cross domain is forbidden on client side for security matters, but on server side you do as you wish.

The difference here is that you have to reload a page in order for it to query the other domain and then push it to your page. So basically you could do the following :

1- Your javascript does an ajax request to it's own domain.
2- On the server side, you make a cross domain request
3- You print some js/html to be used by the requester

In that scenario, you have one more request than doing it directly on the client side.

Comment: Hmm I see.. I guess I can now even do the on demand loading of additional javascripts with new content and in such a way simulete more ajax calls. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

As Pointy commented, this is essentially the same as JSONP.  Keep in mind that most browsers block sending cookies to the 3rd party site though.

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain is possible as long as the server sends an access-control-allow-origin response header. See the linked article for an example

http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html

Comment: Doesn't work with IE6 and 7 unless user manually change security settings :((