# jQuery alternative to iframe so to modify css for external domain's content

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

Modify css of external content???

So is this possible or is their a work around to accomplish this. I am trying to use the jQuery load function to replace content that I would, in the past, use an iframe for. I am not sure if the load function works on external domains though?? I am doing this so that when it loads the content the css in altered. I know you cant use custom css for an external iframe cause this would cause some serious security risks.

Anyone with an idea on how to accomplish this

My Website, Internal Domain

```
<style>
#internal-domain{
  font-size:18px;
  color:#000000;
}
</style>

<body>

<b>Footer navigation:</b>
<ol id="internal-domain"></ol>

<script>
$( "#internal-domain" ).load( "http://external-domain.com/test.html #external-domain-div" );
</script>

</body>
```

External Domain's css

```
#external-domain-div{
  font-size:14px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: This gets difficult because of cross-domain content restrictions.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523858/cross-domain-content-loading-with-javascript

Comment: Well the only advantage I have in this is that the external domain is a company I am working with. They cannot modify much on their end but if they needed to add a couple lines of code that would allow me to do this they would, as long as it didn't compromise the security of things on their end.

Comment: Then adding this to the external site's outgoing http headers will let you perform an ajax request:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.site-jquery-is-on.com

Whether this is compatible with $().load(), I'm not sure.

Comment: Test it first on a subdomain of your site.  That will let you work out the cross-domain complexities privately.